# GoLand: How to replace AWS SDK GO V1 import suggestions with V2

Tags: go, goland, aws-sdk-go

I am working with *GoLand* (JetBrains IDE for golang) accessing the AWS services with the corresponding SDK. Every time I'm using a service client for the first time I want to use the "auto-import" feature of *GoLand* to import the SDK. The IDE then offers to import `.../aws-sdk-go/...` (see image below). But there is already a new version of the AWS SDK GO, namely `.../aws-sdk-go-v2/...`. Right now I let *GoLand* import V1 and change the go.mod file afterwards by updating the corresponding line to V2.

Is there a way to tell *GoLand* to only suggest imports for V2 instead of V1?

[image: Goland tries to import SDK GO V1 instead of V2]

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add imports you want to omit from completion/imports from `Settings/Preferences | Go | Imports | Exclude from import and completion`.

Comment: Thanks. It is now excluded but is there also the possibility to add the V2 to the "auto-import" suggestions without adding the respective packages via *go get*? Since I get no suggestions now for packages that are not added to project yet. Like adding `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/*` somewhere in the  import settings.